# Autofac generic delegate factory

Tags: c#, autofac

I would like to register a generic delegate factory for all type or class : is there a way to do it ? Here under a solution that works for registering one type/class at a time.... not very good any other way to do ?

```
    public class Foo<T>

    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public T Value;

    }

    public class FooBuilder<T>

    {

        public Foo<T> Build(string name)

        {

            return new Foo<T> { Name = name };

        }

    }


    public delegate Foo<T> FooFactory<T>(string name);



    public static void TestFoo()

    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<FooBuilder<double>>();

        builder.Register<FooFactory<double>>(c =>    c.Resolve<FooBuilder<double>>().Build);

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        var foo1 = container.Resolve<FooFactory<double>>()("foo1");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register 'open generics' as providing a service. For your example:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// This registers an open generic that can provide all FooBuilder<T>.
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FooBuilder<>));

var container = builder.Build();

// Resolve the builder directly...
var fooBuilder = container.Resolve<FooBuilder<double>>();

// ...or get a factory method if that's what you need
var fooBuilderFactory = container.Resolve<Func<FoodBuilder<double>>>();
```